# How to fix Linux kernel (HWE) vulnerabilities (USN-3980-2) (MDSUM/RIDL) on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: kernel, updates, security, azure

When I performed a Tenable scan on my Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS machine it reported the below vulnerability.

> Ubuntu 18.04 LTS : Linux kernel (HWE) vulnerabilities (USN-3980-2) (MDSUM/RIDL) (MFBDS/RIDL/ZombieLoad) (MLPDS/RIDL) (MSBDS/Fallout)

Upon checking, I found the solution in the Ubuntu official document

https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-3980-2

> The problem can be corrected by updating your system to the following
> package versions:
>
> ```
> Ubuntu 18.04
> linux-image-4.18.0-1018-azure - 4.18.0-1018.18~18.04.1
> linux-image-4.18.0-20-generic - 4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1
> linux-image-4.18.0-20-generic-lpae - 4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1
> linux-image-4.18.0-20-lowlatency - 4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1
> linux-image-4.18.0-20-snapdragon - 4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1
> linux-image-azure - 4.18.0.1018.17
> linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 - 4.18.0.20.70
> linux-image-generic-lpae-hwe-18.04 - 4.18.0.20.70
> linux-image-lowlatency-hwe-18.04 - 4.18.0.20.70
> linux-image-snapdragon-hwe-18.04 - 4.18.0.20.70
> linux-image-virtual-hwe-18.04 - 4.18.0.20.70
> ```

But anybody knows to which package I need to update? and how to perform the update?

My ubuntu server is running on the Azure cloud server and details are given below.

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.18.0-1013-azure x86_64)

Thanks

Comment: Performing a normal update should also upgrade your kernel: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. This would naturally install the `linux-image-4.18.0-1018-azure` package, unless I'm really missing out something?

Comment: But why are you running 18.04.2, when the latest point release is 18.04.5? And that USN is 1,5 years old - what's going on here?

Comment: @ArturMeinild, the machine is provisioned almost 2 years back with the available Ubuntu image in azure, after that, I have installed few applications but didn't perform an upgrade